# Angular JS filter an array with search input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, angularjs-filter

So, my problem is that I want to create an search input field, which I have already done and I am using a search filter in an ng-repeat. What I want now to do is to select all the items I searched for using the select all checkbox.In this moment when I click the select all checkbox it checks all of my items from my array not from what I searched.

This is my html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
                    <div>
                        <md-input-container flex> <label>Search</label>
                        <input ng-model="search.name"> </md-input-container>
                        <md-button class="md-primary" ng-click="saveValues()">Update</md-button>
                        </div>



    <div class="md-list">
     <md-checkbox ng-model="modelItemsList.allItemsSelected" 
                        ng-change="selectAll()">
                        Select all
                         </md-checkbox>
                            <md-list> <md-list-item class="md-3-line"
                                ng-repeat="mod

elItem in modelItemsList | filter:search">
                        <div class="md-list-item-text">
                            <md-checkbox ng-model="modelItem.isChecked " aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-change="selectModelItem(modelItem)">
                            <h3>{{ $eval('modelItem.'+propertyName) }}</h3>
                            <p>{{ $eval('modelItem.'+propertyDesc) }}</p>
                             </md-checkbox>
                        </div>
                        </md-list-item> </md-list> 
                    </div>
                </div>
```

This is my select all function:

```
$scope.selectAll = function(){
                 console.debug("searchText", $scope.search);
                 //filteredArray = filterFilter($rootScope.modelItemsList, $scope.search);
                 //console.log(filteredArray);
                 console.log($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected);
                 $rootScope.temp = [];
                 console.log($scope.modelItemsList);
                 $rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected = !$rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected;
                 console.log($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected);
                 if($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected){
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.modelItemsList.length; i++) {
                        $rootScope.temp.push($scope.modelItemsList[i].name);
                        console.log($scope.modelItemsList[i].name);
                        $scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked = $rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected;
                        console.log($scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked);
                        console.log($rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected);
                    }
                 }
                 else if (!$rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected){
                     for (var i = 0; i < $scope.modelItemsList.length; i++) {
                     $scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked = $rootScope.modelItemsList.allItemsSelected;
                     $rootScope.temp = [];
                     console.log($scope.modelItemsList[i].isChecked);
                     }
                }
            }
```

I think I should make some kind of filter, but I am not so sure. I mean in my JS file in the select all function. Does anybody have any idea how should I do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to use $eval in the view, it's bad practice and I don't see why you need to do that here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to name the filtered list:

ie

```
<md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="modelItem in filtered = ( modelItemsList | filter:search )">
    ...
</md-list-item>
```

Then in the controller you can access `$scope.filtered`

---

FYI

you can change `{{ $eval('modelItem.'+propertyDesc) }}` to 
`{{ modelItem[propertyDesc] }}`

Comment: I did already that part. What I want to do is to check if my array modelItemsList contains something I searched for. Something like comparing modelItemsList with the filtered array

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: When I search for something I get the list that matched my searches, right ? And what I want to do is to select that with the select all checkbox, but right now my select all function selects all the items from my modelItemsList, but when I search for something I want to select only what is displayed(what I searched for) not all my array.

Comment: Can you post your code for ```function selectAll()```

Comment: So if I've understood correctly you only want to select the ones which have been filtered. So instead of looping through ```$scope.modelItemsList```, you want to loop through $scope.filtered

Comment: I want first to check that what I searched for resembles something I have already in my modelItemsList. For ex, if my array contains something like var a = ["banana", "apple", "pineapple"], and I search for apple what would get displayed is apple and pineapple, right ? Now, what I want is to loop over apple and pineapple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but you weren't very clear in your question. From what I understand, this is what you want.

> What I want now to do is to select all the items I searched for using the select all checkbox

Check out this plunkr where it's implemented.

https://plnkr.co/edit/vjzJEm8Wck8b5iUD4qz8?p=preview

The way you could do this is by setting up ng-change on your select all checkbox

`<input type="checkbox" ng-change="selectAllFiltered()"  ng-model="checkbox.value2" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false"/>`

Next, you would define the selectAllFiltered method in your controller. The objective is to set `isSelected` on `$scope.filtered` array when the array is filtered.

And when the array is NOT filtered, i.e. there is no string in the search.name field, then set `isSelected` on `$scope.modelItemsList` array.

Here's what your controller method should look like...

```js
$scope.selectAllFiltered = function() {

    if ($scope.checkbox.selectAll) {
      $scope.checkbox.selectAll = false;
    } else {
      $scope.checkbox.selectAll = true;
    }
    
    if (!$scope.search.name) {
      console.log('when no name is entered')
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.modelItemsList.length; i++) {
        if (angular.isUndefined($scope.modelItemsList[i].isSelected)) {
          $scope.modelItemsList[i].isSelected = $scope.checkbox.selectAll;
        } else {
          $scope.modelItemsList[i].isSelected = !$scope.modelItemsList[i].isSelected;
        }

      }
    } else {
      console.log('when some name is entered');
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filtered.length; i++) {
        if (angular.isUndefined($scope.filtered[i].isSelected)) {
          $scope.filtered[i].isSelected = $scope.checkbox.selectAll;
        } else {
          $scope.filtered[i].isSelected = !$scope.filtered[i].isSelected;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```